# why product of two path homotopy class is not always defined?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

This is a question regarding lack of formation of  Fundamental Group, could any one give an easy example why the product of two path homotopy class is not defined in a space $X$?
Thank you.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking... Is the fact that there is no sensible way to multiply the path $\alpha:t\in[0,1]\mapsto t\in\mathbb R$ and the path $\beta:t\in[0,1]\mapsto t+42\in\mathbb R$, both in the space $\mathbb R$, an example that satisfies you?

Comment: Aha! Thank you! got it!, but then why we can define product of two path while they have same starting point and end point? I mean to say loop.

Comment: If two paths have the same start and end points, then they can be concatenated to produce another path with the same start and end point, the same sort of thing you started with. No such luck with two random paths.

Comment: @Neal: Sounds like that'd make a good answer :)

Comment: Note that just accepting $\alpha + \beta$ as a "formal sum of paths" even when you cannot concatenate them is the construct upon which simplicical homology is built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two paths have the same start and end points, then they can be concatenated to produce another path with the same start and end point. That's the same sort of thing you started with, which should give you hope that perhaps you can build an algebraic object out of paths starting and ending at the same point. However, you have no such luck with two random paths.